# Broadleaf 5.2 - How do I set ProductOptions into a newly created Product via the API?

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

**Problem**:

I am seeing that the Product "*setProductOptions*()" method has been deprecated, and that the "*setProductOptionXrefs*()" is preferred.  The issue is that I can't seem to find any example of how to set the ProductOptionXrefs.

I've looked for examples within the Broadleaf "*BroadleafCommerce-develop-5.2.x*" and "*DemoSite-broadleaf-5.2.2.1-GA*" projects as well as combed the galaxy for an example.  No luck.

**The Goal (X)**:

I am creating an endpoint that will take in a JSON object and accept two parameters, (*categoryName* and *price*).

The endpoint will:

- Find the category that the product will belong to.
- Create a new Sku object and populate with some of the input *wrapper* fields.
- Create a new Product object and populate a few *wrapper* fields.
- Assign a ProductOption to this new Product. **<== X**
- Save the Product.
- Return a response (for the REST response).

The endpoint itself looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my_product", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public ProductWrapper addCSDLProduct(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody ProductWrapper wrapper,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "categoryName", required = true) String categoryName,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "price", required = true) double price) {

    Category category = null;
    List<Category> categories = catalogService.findCategoriesByName( categoryName );
    if ( categories != null && categories.size() > 0 ) {
        category = categories.get(0);
    }

    Sku defaultSku = catalogService.createSku();
    defaultSku.setRetailPrice(new Money( price ));
    defaultSku.setInventoryType( InventoryType.ALWAYS_AVAILABLE );
    defaultSku.setName( wrapper.getName() );
    defaultSku.setLongDescription( wrapper.getLongDescription() );
    defaultSku.setDescription( wrapper.getDescription() );
    defaultSku.setUrlKey( wrapper.getUrl() );
    defaultSku.setActiveStartDate( new Date() );

    Product product = catalogService.createProduct(ProductType.PRODUCT);
    product.setDefaultSku(defaultSku);        
    product.setUrl( wrapper.getUrl() );
    product.setCategory(category);  

    List<ProductOptionXref> productOptionXrefs = new ArrayList<ProductOptionXref>();
    List<ProductOption> allProductOptions = catalogService.readAllProductOptions();        
    if ( null != allProductOptions && allProductOptions.size() > 0 ) {
        for ( ProductOption po : allProductOptions ) {          
            String current = po.getName();
            if ( current.equalsIgnoreCase("Shirt Color") ) {
                ProductOptionXref productOptionXref = new ProductOptionXrefImpl();
                productOptionXref.setProductOption(po);
                productOptionXrefs.add(productOptionXref);
            }               
        }
    }

    product.setProductOptionXrefs(productOptionXrefs);

    Product finalProduct = catalogService.saveProduct(product);
    Long newId = finalProduct.getId();

    ProductWrapper response;
    response = (ProductWrapper) context.getBean(ProductWrapper.class.getName());
    response.wrapDetails(product, request);
    response.setId(newId);

    return response;
}
```

The input object (an example) I use is:

```
{
    "name": "This is the name of the product.",
    "description": "This is the description of the product.",
    "longDescription": "This is a long description of the product. Really long.",
    "url": "/this/is/the/url/of/the/product",
    "defaultSku": {
        "name": "This is the name of the product.",
        "active": true,
        "available": true,
        "inventoryType": "ALWAYS_AVAILABLE",
        "retailPrice": {
            "amount": 19.0,
            "currency": "USD"
        }
    }
}
```

With a *catgoryName* of "Merchandise" and a *price* of 19.00.

This code above is currently returning a "Not-null" error:

> Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance
>   must be saved before current operation:
>   org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.ProductOptionXrefImpl.product
>   -> org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.ProductImpl; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property
>   references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before
>   current operation:
>   org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.ProductOptionXrefImpl.product
>   -> org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.ProductImpl

which most likely has to do with my

```
if ( current.equalsIgnoreCase("Shirt Color") ) {
  ProductOptionXref productOptionXref = new ProductOptionXrefImpl();
  productOptionXref.setProductOption(po);
  productOptionXrefs.add(productOptionXref);
}
```

and/or

```
Product finalProduct = catalogService.saveProduct(product);
```

lines just above.

I could (eventually) figure out the "Not-null" error, but the question I ask is if anyone has an example of adding a ProductOption or ProductOptionXref to a newly created Product?

Thanks

Jon

**[UPDATE]**

I wanted to update my question with the solution, much thanks to @phillipuniverse for the example/explanations.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my_product", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public ProductWrapper addCSDLProduct(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody ProductWrapper wrapper,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "categoryName", required = true) String categoryName,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "price", required = true) double price) {

    Category category = null;
    List<Category> categories = catalogService.findCategoriesByName( categoryName );
    if ( categories != null && categories.size() > 0 ) {
        category = categories.get(0);
    }

    Sku defaultSku = catalogService.createSku();
    defaultSku.setRetailPrice(new Money( price ));
    defaultSku.setInventoryType( InventoryType.ALWAYS_AVAILABLE );
    defaultSku.setName( wrapper.getName() );
    defaultSku.setLongDescription( wrapper.getLongDescription() );
    defaultSku.setDescription( wrapper.getDescription() );
    defaultSku.setUrlKey( wrapper.getUrl() );
    defaultSku.setActiveStartDate( new Date() );

    Product product = catalogService.createProduct(ProductType.PRODUCT);
    product.setDefaultSku(defaultSku);        
    product.setUrl( wrapper.getUrl() );
    product.setCategory(category);  

    List<ProductOptionXref> productOptionXrefs = new ArrayList<ProductOptionXref>();
    List<ProductOption> allProductOptions = catalogService.readAllProductOptions();        
    if ( null != allProductOptions && allProductOptions.size() > 0 ) {
        for ( ProductOption po : allProductOptions ) {          
            String current = po.getName();
            if ( current.equalsIgnoreCase("Shirt Color") ) {
                ProductOptionXref productOptionXref = new ProductOptionXrefImpl();
                productOptionXref.setProductOption(po);
                productOptionXref.setProduct(product);
                productOptionXrefs.add(productOptionXref);
            }               
        }
    }

    product.setProductOptionXrefs(productOptionXrefs);

    Product finalProduct = catalogService.saveProduct(product);
    finalProduct.getDefaultSku().setDefaultProduct(finalProduct);
    catalogService.saveSku(finalProduct.getDefaultSku());        
    Long newId = finalProduct.getId();

    ProductWrapper response;
    response = (ProductWrapper) context.getBean(ProductWrapper.class.getName());
    response.wrapDetails(product, request);
    response.setId(newId);

    return response;
}
```

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the majority of what you have there is correct. You are missing a back-reference with the default Sku though; admittedly it's a little weird. You've got this part right:

```
Product product = catalogService.createProduct(ProductType.PRODUCT);
product.setDefaultSku(defaultSku);
```

But then you also need to make sure that the default sku references back to the product; you have the save the product first and then set it:

```
...
Product finalProduct = catalogService.saveProduct(product);
finalProduct.getDefaultSku().setDefaultProduct(finalProduct);
catalogService.saveSku(finalProduct.getDefaultSku());
```

> This code above is currently returning a "Not-null" error:

You are right, the problem is in this code, and it is because you are not setting the `product` property on the `ProductOptionXrefImpl`:

```
if ( current.equalsIgnoreCase("Shirt Color") ) {
    ProductOptionXref productOptionXref = new ProductOptionXrefImpl();
    productOptionXref.setProductOption(po);
    productOptionXrefs.add(productOptionXref);
}
```

If you look at the `product` property in `ProductOptionXrefImpl` you will find this:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = ProductImpl.class, optional=false, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
protected Product product = new ProductImpl();
```

You are getting past the `optional=false` part, but the `new ProductImpl()` part makes it always be a 'transient' instance with Hibernate; it does not have an ID property and Hibernate doesn't know anything about it. Since the `cascade` is set to only `REFRESH`, Hibernate also doesn't try to persist it or anything (which it shouldn't).

The fix is to set the `product` property on the option xref:

```
if ( current.equalsIgnoreCase("Shirt Color") ) {
    ProductOptionXref productOptionXref = new ProductOptionXrefImpl();
    productOptionXref.setProductOption(po);
    productOptionXref.setProduct(product);
    productOptionXrefs.add(productOptionXref);
}
```

I *think* this will work, but you might have to move the product option creation to below your first save of the Product, and set it to `finalProduct`. But I think as-written all of the cascades will figure it out.

Comment: Yes, that works.  I appreciate the quick response and examples, as well as taking the time to explain/teach the reasoning behind the solution.  I was able to implement and test within a few minutes.  Thanks @phillipuniverse.